# Relationships in sqllite database no foreign key added

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create relationship from Post to User model. So I create:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :text, :title, :image, :user_id
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

and in User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :posts
end
```

Then I add file to database migration:

```
class AddUserIdToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And made migration via rake db:migration.

When I add new post the value of user_id (in dataBase) is empty, but column exists.

Part of Post_Controller:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What should I do with @post = Post.new(params[:post])? I think that everything is fine...

Comment: You might need to make `:user_id` `attr_accessible` in the `Post` class

Comment: I add :user_id but nothing changed. I check database and I still have empty values on user_id (table Posts)

Comment: Where are you giving `user_id` a value? Is it inside `params[:post]`?

Comment: I don't know what is inside params[:post] in my opinion its all of attributes. I also added images with no problems and I didn't change params[:post].

Answer (score 0):

```
attr_accessible :text, :title, :image, :user_id
```

or, instead of attr_accessible, just do this:

```
attr_protected
```

Comment: I added the :user_id but nothing changed. I check database and I still have empty values on user_id (table Posts).

Comment: I can't make attr_protected becouse I get error: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PostsController#create "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, text"

Comment: The problem was with parama[:post] => its add all fields from form. There wasn't id of user so it didn't added to database :)
Link for problem:
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38077